# Android layouts: Center a View but respect a corner view

Tags: android, layout

I need to make an element centered in ~Linear layout, and there is a second corner element that is mostly out of the way.

But the center element may grow to start covering the corner element.
Is there a layout that would allow me to make sure they do not overlap in such situation?

To illustate:

```
------------------------------------------
               |Center el|     |corner el|

------------------------------------------
        |Center el gets longer||corner el|
         
------------------------------------------
|Center el is respecting corner|corner el|
```

Edit:
I have experimented with ConstraintLayout, but the constraints are all either  "springy" - actively pushing one component away from the other, or chained - attaching one component to the other. A constraint with spring factor of 0 would be needed.

Messing around with Margins and bias kinda works if the corner container width is known, but does not give accurate results.

Comment: You can implement this with a `ConstraintLayout` and barriers I'd say

Comment: yes you can do it, constrinay layout allows you to do that with multiple ways, take a look at this document https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: Updated the Q, I have tried the Constraint Layout already. If you have a concrete solution that would be great

Answer (score 0):

you could use [android:weightSum](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout#attr_android:weightSum) to solve your problem.

Then your LinearLayout should be something like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:weightSum="3">

      <TextView
         android:text="Center el is respecting corner"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_weight="2"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

      <TextView
        android:text="corner el"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Not exactly unfortunately. This results in the corner element always occupying 33% and the center view always being off parents center by 33%